# New Range Outlet

Tags: gfci, range

Quick two-part question.  The wife and I recently bought a gas range to replace our electric.  Aside from having to extend the existing gas line, I also need to install a 120v outlet in the wall behind the stove; only a 220v outlet there now.  Thought the simplest way to do this would be to fish a wire down from the microwave outlet above.  Once I pulled the cover off and outlet out of the box, I see there is a 3-wire and 4-wire coming into it.  It took me a little while to figure out that the supply is the 4-wire with the red and black wires on separate 20A breakers.  The red looks like the dedicated circuit for the microwave and the black wire feeds a GFCI and a chain of 5 normal outlets along the counter below.

My first question, is there any problem with tapping into the circuit (black wire) feeding the GFCI outlets when all circuits share the same 12awg neutral wire?

And the second, I’ve read that the piezo-igniters on the stove can trip GFCIs.  I’m assuming this is mainly a problem when the stove is downstream from the GFCI, but would it be a problem if the stove was 4-5’ upstream from the GFCI?

For what it’s worth, I don’t expect the range’s current draw to be significant since it only runs the electronics, igniters, oven lights and convection fan.  Please correct me if I am wrong here?

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

### This is OK

While adding *arbitrary* things to kitchen countertop receptacle circuits is no good according to NEC 210.52(B)(2):

> **(2) No Other Outlets.** The two or more small-appliance
>   branch circuits specified in 210.52(B)(1) shall have no other
>   outlets.
>
> *Exception No. 1: A receptacle installed solely for the electrical supply to
>   and support of an electric clock in any of the rooms specified in
>   210.52(B)(1).*
>
> *Exception No. 2: Receptacles installed to provide power for supplemental equipment and lighting on gas-fired ranges, ovens, or counter-mounted cooking units.*

as you can see, Exception 2 to NEC 210.52(B) permits what you are doing.  Also, a properly functioning GFCI will not get influenced by the stove on the LINE side of the circuit. (The issue with spark-ignited gas ranges on GFCIs is that cooktop spark igniters are not isolated from mains, yet use the range chassis as a HV return path.)

So, I would simply drop down from the junction point you are looking at with 12/2 W/G and fit a single 120V, 20A receptacle in a single-gang box behind the gas range for it to plug into.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the receptacle for the stove on the branch circuit for the counter top appliances.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the fine answers already submitted, you can pigtail one of the 120V legs from the 240V supply with a piece of #12AWG and hook it into a 120V outlet. Do the same to the supply neutral and also hook up your ground. Add a 20A breaker and pigtail a piece Of #12 AWG to the 120v leg you're using and disconnect the range breaker but leave it there in case you ever go back to electric.

Your Piezo igniter will not affect a GFCI if it is upstream from the GFCI.

Comment: Where would you add the new 20 A breaker? In the panel with the other breakers?

Comment: @mkeith Yes, in the main panel.

Comment: The picture is clear to me now. Thank you!

Comment: This would be my first choice, but just a note, if you have an old 3 wire (NEMA10) receptacle you may not have the proper wire colors to use this method legally.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Very true. The OP stated he had a 4 wire supply and three wire run on two 20A breakers. The 4 wire supply should be 2 legs, neutral and ground.  That was my understanding.

Comment: @JACK I understood the 4 wire to be a MWBC feeding through the microwave box, I thought you were recommending modifying the range circuit.